# How to make a custom selection of rows in dataTable to be exported?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am using dataTables to display my data. But, I want to make custom selection rows to be exported. I already create a remove button in every row and it removes the selected row. But, when I export the data, the removed rows is also exported. This is my current code:

```
$('.dataTables').DataTable({                               
    pageLength  : 25,
    responsive  : true,
    dom         : '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
    buttons     : [
                    {extend: 'copy'},
                    {extend: 'csv', title: "Laporan Penomoran"},
                    {extend: 'excel', title: "Laporan Penomoran"},
                    {extend: 'pdf', title: "Laporan Penomoran"},
                    {extend: 'print',
                        customize: function (win){
                            $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
                            $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');
                            $(win.document.body).find('table').addClass('compact').css('font-size', 'inherit');
                        }
                    }
    ]

});
```

Comment: I don't personnaly use this (great) plugin but it looks like you should be able to set specific rows (the ones not 'removed') using [rows option](https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector) (passing e.g jQuery selector or array) of [buttons.exportData() API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons.exportData()). I'm not sure how you wish to handle paginated data though. Maybe if you provide a minimalistic sample with your exact expected behaviour, it would be easier to help on this one.

Comment: I think this helps you. Please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585936/select-row-in-single-click-in-datatable-and-export-selected-data-as-excel

Comment: Please show how you remove rows.